# Call database seeder from a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to create a set of database seed classes specifically for adding data for test cases I'm writing.

My plan was to put them in the folder:

```
app/database/seeds/testData/
```

and then call the seeder via the command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class="testData/myTestSeeder"
```

But I get a "class does not exist" error.

Is it possible to call database seeders that live in a subfolder in seeds? I don't see an explicit "yes" in the docs, but I don't see an explicit "no" either.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You shouldn't need to edit your `classmap` on your project, just make sure to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

after moving your class to a subfolder.

Once you've done that, run this (no need to mention testData here)

```
php artisan db:seed --class="myTestSeeder"
```

Comment: The dump of the autoload and removing the subfolder name worked for me without the need to modify my `composer.json` file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the autoloader how to load your new class.  This is relatively simple; add the following to your composer.json in the `classmap` property:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/database/seeds/testData"  // <-- Add this
    ]
},
```

After that, run `composer dump-autoload` and your seed file should now be loaded successfully.

Comment: Are the seed classes in the subfolder not autoloaded from the classmap `"app/database/seeds"`? I'm giving your method a try now, I'm just curious as I'm still learning about composer and how it works.

Comment: No. Another solution can be to add a namespace to your seed and then register it with the auotloader in a "psr-0" key underneath the `autoload` property

Answer (score 1):

When you create new Seeder class, for example:

```
php artisan make:seeder Authorization/CreateAppRoleSeeder
```

As a result, get new class:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class Authorization/CreateAppRoleSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

You have to replace `class Authorization/CreateAppRoleSeeder extends Seeder`
with `class CreateAppRoleSeeder extends Seeder`.

Next, execute the dump composer command:

```
composer dump
```

After add class to file 'database\Seeder\DatabaseSeeder'
In my case, for example:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Seed the application's database.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            $this->call(CreateAppRoleSeeder::class);
        }
    }
```

After that execute the command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

In my case

```
php artisan db:seed --class=CreateAppRoleSeeder
```

So will work ;)